# psycopg2: не получается подключится к БД PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, pycharm, psycopg2

Пытаюсь подключиться к БД PostgreSQL через PyCharm. Через импортированный модуль psycopg2 не выходит, хотя делаю все по документации.

Код:

```py
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="warehouse", user="postgres", password="123456", host="localhost", port="5432")
conn.close()
```

БД создана в `pgAdmin4`.

На выходе выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\conf.py", line 3, in <module>
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="warehouse", user="postgres", password="123456", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432")
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError
```